# Android Chrome renders Roboto instead of Tahoma

Tags: android, google-chrome, fonts

I have a strange issue which Chrome.
I've defined my font-family like this:

```
font-family: Tahoma,Helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

This works just fine in all browsers on Mac,Windows,iOS and Android. Excpet of Google Chrome in Android.
Via remote debuggin, I figured out that Chrome renders the font `Roboto`. I have absolutly no idea why this is happening, since I never used this font in my CSS.

Does anyone know why Chrome is doing this? Alle other browsers are using `Tahoma` but Chrome uses `Roboto` without any particular reason.

Comment: "since I never used this font in my CSS" -- AFAIK, it is up to the browser to determine what to use for the default `sans-serif` font, and it does not surprise me in the least that an Android browser would use Ruboto. Android does not have Microsoft fonts (Tahoma, Arial), and it would not surprise me if they do not have Helvetica variants either.

Comment: The truly surprising thing here is your claim it renders fine in "all browsers... on Android". What browser are you using on Android that *is* somehow capable of rendering Tahoma out of thin air?

Comment: You are right. `All browsers` is maybe a bit over the top. I did not test it by myself. I tested it only with the standard browser, Chrome and Firefox. Firefox is using Tahoma, the other two  are using Roboto. The other browsers were tested by the rest of the team and I assumed that it is working there since I did not get any other feedback...

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for this information. I will follow up on this topic.